# Pass argument to Elastic MapReduce streaming step

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

Is it possible to pass arguments to your streaming steps in Amazon EMR? There seems to be an "extra args" field but the parameters seems to be passed to the streaming jar and not the streaming script itself.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should just work by including them in your --mapper argument so to pass 'arg1' and 'arg2' to a mapper app at the location s3://bucket/script you would use the argument:

```
--mapper 's3://bucket/script arg1 arg2'
```

It might also depend on what client you are using to launch the job. The above works with the ruby [elastic-mapreduce](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2264) client. Of course, you'll also need to provide other arguments.